# My upload script works only on my computer

Tags: php, mysql

My upload script works in 100% only on computers in my network, when some else network is used(another location) it uploads an image into ftp server, but it doesn't save its title in Mysql db. Looks like it hasn't got access to database from another location.
Here's code:

```
session_start();

require 'config2.php';
require_once 'user.class.php';

 $target = "sent/"; 
 $target1 = "sent/";
 $target2 = "sent/";
  $target3 = "sent/";
$target4 = "sent/";
$target5 = "sent/";

$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 
$target1 = $target1 . basename( $_FILES['photo1']['name']); 
$target2 = $target2 . basename( $_FILES['photo2']['name']);
$target3 = $target3 . basename( $_FILES['photo3']['name']);
$target4 = $target4 . basename( $_FILES['photo4']['name']);
$target5 = $target5 . basename( $_FILES['photo5']['name']);

  //This gets all the other information from the form 
$login = $_SESSION['login'];    
$name=$_POST['name']; 
$name1 =$_POST['name1'];
 $name2 =$_POST['name2'];
$name3 =$_POST['name3'];
$name4 =$_POST['name4'];
$name5 =$_POST['name5'];
$pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']); 
$pic1=($_FILES['photo1']['name']); 
$pic2=($_FILES['photo2']['name']); 
$pic3=($_FILES['photo3']['name']); 
$pic4=($_FILES['photo4']['name']); 
$pic5=($_FILES['photo5']['name']); 

$id=$_SESSION['id'];
// Connects to your Database 

  mysql_query("UPDATE users SET name='$name', name1='$name1', name2='$name2', name3='$name3', name4='$name4', name5='$name5', photo = '$pic', photo1 = '$pic1', photo2 = '$pic2', photo3 = '$pic3', photo4 = '$pic4', photo5 = '$pic5' WHERE  login = '$login' ");


$allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');  

//Writes the photo to the server 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'] ,$target) )
{ 




  //Tells you if its all ok 
echo "Plik ". basename( $_FILES['photo']['name'] ). " uploaded successfuly"; 
echo implode(', ', $allowed);
} 


f(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo1']['tmp_name'] ,$target1) )
{ 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
 echo "Plik ". basename( $_FILES['photo1']['name'] ). " uploaded successfuly"; 
echo implode(', ', $allowed);
 } 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo2']['tmp_name'] ,$target2) )
 { 

//Tells you if its all ok 
 echo "Plik ". basename( $_FILES['photo2']['name'] ). " uploaded successfuly"; 
echo implode(', ', $allowed);
 } 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo3']['tmp_name'] ,$target3) )
{ 

//Tells you if its all ok 
echo "Plik ". basename( $_FILES['photo3']['name'] ). " uploaded successfuly"; 
echo implode(', ', $allowed);
 } 

 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo4']['tmp_name'] ,$target4) )
 { 

 //Tells you if its all ok 
 echo "Plik ". basename( $_FILES['photo4']['name'] ). " uploaded successfuly"; 
echo implode(', ', $allowed);
} 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo5']['tmp_name'] ,$target5) )
{ 

//Tells you if its all ok 
 echo "Plik ". basename( $_FILES['photo5']['name'] ). " uploaded successfuly"; 
 echo implode(', ', $allowed);
```

Do You know how to fix it? Maybe You can see error/s, Every help welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create target path with

```
$docRoot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$target = $docRoot."/sent/". basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);;
```

and check folder permission on server